# Python kafka: Is there a way to block a consumer on a kafka topic till a new message is posted?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I have a consumer subscribed to a test topic where a producer thread posts regularly. I would like to be able to block the consumer thread until a new message is on - then process that and start waiting again. The closest I came is:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic_name, auto_offset_reset='latest',
                         bootstrap_servers=[localhost_],
                         api_version=(0, 10), consumer_timeout_ms=1000)
while True:
    print(consumer.poll(timeout_ms=5000))
```

Is there a more idiomatic way (or is there any serious problem with this way that I can't see) ?

New to kafka so general advice on this design very welcome. Full (running) example:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

import kafka
from kafka import KafkaProducer, KafkaConsumer

print('python-kafka:', kafka.__version__)

def publish_message(producer_instance, topic_name, key, value):
    try:
        key_bytes = bytes(str(key), encoding='utf-8')
        value_bytes = bytes(str(value), encoding='utf-8')
        producer_instance.send(topic_name, key=key_bytes, value=value_bytes)
        producer_instance.flush()
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception in publishing message\n', ex)

localhost_ = 'localhost:9092'

def kafka_producer():
    _producer = None
    try:
        _producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=[localhost_],
                                  api_version=(0, 10))
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception while connecting Kafka')
        print(str(ex))
    j = 0
    while True:
        publish_message(_producer, topic_name, value=j, key=j)
        j += 1
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Running Producer..')
    topic_name = 'test'
    prod_thread = Thread(target=kafka_producer)
    prod_thread.start()
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic_name, auto_offset_reset='latest',
                             bootstrap_servers=[localhost_],
                             api_version=(0, 10), consumer_timeout_ms=1000)
    # consumer.subscribe([topic_name])
    while True:
        print(consumer.poll(timeout_ms=5000))
```

`python-kafka: 1.3.5`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polling in an infinite loop is what is suggested in [Kafka: The Definitive Guide](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/) as well. Here is a Java excerpt from [Chapter 4. Kafka Consumers: Reading Data from Kafka](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/ch04.html) using the same idea:

```
try {
    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
        ...
    }
}
```

This translates well to how the libraries are recommended to be used in Python.

**kafka-python** (see full example in [A Tale of Two Kafka Clients](https://blog.datasyndrome.com/a-tale-of-two-kafka-clients-c613efab49df))

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
...
kafka_consumer = Consumer(
...
)
consumer.subscribe([topic])

running = True
while running:
    message = kafka_consumer.poll()
...
```

**confluent-kafka-python** (see full example in [Introduction to Apache Kafka for Python Programmers](https://www.confluent.io/blog/introduction-to-apache-kafka-for-python-programmers/))

```
from confluent_kafka import Consumer, KafkaError
...
c = Consumer(settings)

c.subscribe(['mytopic'])

try:
    while True:
        msg = c.poll(0.1)
...
```

Another tightly related question that could come up is how you process the messages.

This part of your code might rely on external dependencies (databases, remote services, network filesystems, etc.) and that could result in failed processing attempts.

So it could be a good idea to implement a retry logic, you can find a good description of how that would look like in the blog post [Retrying consumer architecture in the Apache Kafka](https://blog.pragmatists.com/retrying-consumer-architecture-in-the-apache-kafka-939ac4cb851a).

Comment: Note: The question was using python

Comment: @cricket_007 The same idea is used with the Python libraries, I've added reference to those as well.

Comment: More complete examples can be found at https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/consumer.html#advanced-examples

Comment: @OneCricketeer Does this line:   `for msg in consumer:` will infinitely consumes messages as written [here](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/usage.html#:~:text=for%20message%20in%20consumer%3A) ? If not whether wrapping this under a while True loop will work?

Comment: I just want to know whether it can be done without polling.

Comment: @y_159 It does, but the library you linked to is not `confluent_kafka`, where `poll()` is used